# How "puts" statement works in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.9.3

## I knew that puts return always `nil` by itself.

But knowing that fact already I have started to play around it. here it is:

```
>> puts

=> nil # Good, you are doing what I expected.

>> puts 15
15
=> nil # nil is for puts and 15 it printed,as it is assigned to do. perfect still.

>> puts a = 5 + 2
7
=> nil # still good.
```

Now I will do a bit more with `puts` to see how robust it is.

```
>> puts a= 5 + 2;b= 2+3
7
=> 5 #ahh! where is nil?

>> puts a= 5 + 2;b= 2+3;c= 4+8
7
=> 12 # again no nil. Another confusion created here that why 12 and 7 only, how 5 has been skipped?
```

***How `puts` `nil` value has been suppressed ?***

Okay, so lets test another way where `nil` has been gone.

```
>> x=puts a= 5 + 2;b= 2+3;c= 4+8
7
=> 12

>> puts x

=> nil # humm, nil is there. but why not nil => nil? Confusion here again goes up. whose nil is it?
```

Can anyone help me by saying the actual behaviour of `puts` in Ruby's world?

Comment: Do you know what a `;` does in Ruby?

Comment: why down-vote? what confusion here, what is not clear here?

Comment: You got 3 answers, telling you that in this case the return value of `puts` is ignored in irb but that instead the return value of the last expression is shown. And still, instead of accepting this as an answer, you keep commenting on those answers, that you don't get nil. If you want to get nil there, don't use multiple expressions with semicolons on that one line. **Maybe you want commas instead of semicolons?**

Comment: Why do you expect to see a `=> nil` when you say `puts(a = 7); b = 5`?

Comment: @Conkerchen  humm it sounds good.. `,` prints `nil`. So could you post your point as an answer. And basically what makes it different output with `,` and `;`?

Comment: There are already enough correct answers. This is not about making `nil` show up but about understanding, what ruby/irb does with semicolons.

Comment: @Conkerchen I will when I get the answer of `puts a= 5 + 2;b= 2+3;c= 4+8` statements output. meanwhile let me do more research on it.

Comment: Maybe a simple `puts b` after `puts a= 5 + 2;b= 2+3;c= 4+8` would be helpful.

Comment: why down-vote plese tell me.. so that I can improve my question. Otherwise without explanation down vote making my post quality bad. I put my query fully descriptive manner.

Comment: @user2060534 You keep insisting that the middle expression is being skipped. It is not being skipped, as @muistooshort has pointed out. I think the problem is not that you are confused about how `puts` works but more confused about how `irb` works.

Comment: @CharlesCaldwell Yeah! cool i have accepted the answer. whereas others are also true. but I can accept only one. So I did. It doesn't mean others are wrong. :) but confused why down-vote? :(

Comment: @user2060534 I have no issue with your accepted answer. I haven't provided an answer so it doesn't matter to me. I also haven't downvoted you. I can only speculate as to other people's intentions. Perhaps it is because your comments to the answers seemed to try to make the situation far more complicated than it actually was. Even the comment on your accepted answer seems to suggest you think there are still questions to be answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The repl, `irb` I will assume, is evaluating the statement(s) you enter and displaying the value of the last statement evaluated.

Consider this:

```
>> p = puts "hello"; 5
hello
 => 5 
>> p
 => nil
```

`puts` is still returning `nil` but the repl is displaying the result of the last statement, `5`

Comment: No please look at my all expressions.. you can see it is taking the first and last only. Might be some precedence and associativity works around it.

Comment: The "middle" expressions are not calling `puts` so it appears that it's only "taking" the first and last.

Comment: Basically the arguments to `puts` stop at the first `;` encountered. Everything after the `;` is a new statement for the repl.

Comment: I am not familiared with the short term `repl` sorry :)

Comment: check out [R.E.P.L](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop) and [IRB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interactive_Ruby_Shell)

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't have much to do with puts.

A semicolon separates multiple expressions. `irb` will in this case only display what the last expression evaluated to.

Comment: Plese see my all examples.. and if you are confident with `nil` please show that evidence. I played with as much as I can.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem isn't with `puts`, but what the prompt does with commands containing multiple statements (separated by semi-colons).

Think on this example:

```
irb(main):001:0> "first";"second"
=> "second"
```

Answer (score 1):

`puts`calls `to_s` on it's argument, that's why `puts 1` works. `puts nil` is the same as `puts nil.to_s`, and that is the same as `puts ""` (note the blank line in the IRB output).

The rest is just irb outputting the result of the last executed line, before waiting on new input.

Comment: It is taking only the first and last, how the middles are skipped - that's my question. How it forgot to print the `nil` of its own?

Comment: It does print nil.to_s, which is an empty string. Then irb shows the result of the last statement (after the arrow-like cursor)

Comment: How could you explain the output of `puts a= 5 + 2;b= 2+3` ?