# Confusion with Ruby's output mechanism in IRB with "p","print" and "puts"

Tags: ruby

```
>> p "hi"; puts p "hello"
"hi"
"hello"
hello
=> nil
```

From the output it is pretty clear that `"hi"` and `"hello"` has been printed by two `p`.
then `puts` printed below;

```
hello
=> nil
```

But question is: as `p` returns

```
"hello" 
=> "hello"
```

what `puts` received the left one or the right from `p`? Now to look at that more deeply I tried the below:

```
>> p "hi"; puts print "hello"
"hi"
hello
=> nil
```

Looking at the above, what I understood is that `p` printed its one. Confusions with the below output part.

```
hello
=>nil
```

Is `hello` printed by `print` then where the left hand side of `=> nil`?  If I consider that `puts` has been fired with `print` return value `nil` then the output should come as

```
hello

=>nil # the extra blank line is for `nil.to_s` .
```

But from the actual output I can't conclude that. If I consider that `puts` has been fired with `print` s printed value `hello` then the output should come as

```
hello
=>nil # then where the output of print statement went out?
```

But from the actual output I can't conclude that.

I am using Ubuntu 12.10 and Ruby 1.9.3. Could anyone help me out to understand what's going on?

Comment: If you google "ruby p puts print" you'll get a couple StackOverflow results that explain pretty well what each of those methods does.  And FYI, `p puts print foo` is the same as `p(puts(print(foo)))`.

Comment: @AmitKumarGupta Humm... Amit ji `p puts print foo is the same as p(puts(print(foo)))` that's a good information.

Comment: This seems like it is a duplicate or continuation of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14899116/how-puts-statement-works-in-ruby

Comment: @theTinMan I am sorry to say you that, no way it is connected to that question.This question has a chained construction of `p`,`print` and `puts`.

Comment: `puts p "hello"` is a nonsensical way to print something, and you are wasting your time chasing an answer because nobody would use that. Use `puts "hello"` unless you absolutely need a return value, which `p` provides. You are bogged down on one of the very first things to learn about a language. There are a lot harder things to learn ahead.

Comment: @theTinMan absolutely sir, I am doing that,during reading of my book,I found these and tried with such things to see how those printing statements behave in such a nested situation, and somehow I got stuck to explain myself with the output reasons which I mentioned in my description. But your point is too good - `You are bogged down on one of the very first things to learn about a language. There are a lot harder things to learn ahead.` - I liked your line. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example is the same as

```
p("hi")
puts(print("hello"))
```

The reason that you don't end up with an empty line in the output is that `print` doesn't append a newline to its output.

`print` writes `hello` to stdout, returns nil and then puts writes (on the same line) `nil.to_s` (i.e. the empty string) followed by a newline character, so you get the exact same output as if you had written `puts("hello")`

Comment: There is no difference. Outputs stuff just fine for me